# Firebase Authorization is not checking if the user is logged in properly

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

in my flutter app I want to check if a user is logged in before or not and based on this navigate them to either HomePage or SignIn page. The code I am using is not working fine, it is not navigating to the SignIn page after I've done registration and deleted the account in Firebase Console. In short, when I delete a user, who registered well before, in Firebase Console the application is keeping to show the HomePage and all the posts the user made. How can I handle it?

**"In short, I want to navigate the user to SignIn page after I delete his account in Firebase Console"**

Here is the code in my main.dart file:

```
_check(){
 final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 final User? user = auth.currentUser;
 if(user == null){
   HiveDB.deleteUser();
   return SignInPage();
 }
 HiveDB.putUser(id: user.uid);
 return HomePage();
}

@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
   _check();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: _check(),
    routes: {
      SignInPage.id:(context) => SignInPage(),
      SignUpPage.id:(context) => SignUpPage(),
      HomePage.id:(context) => HomePage(),
    },
  );
}
```

The _check() function is not working as it's desired...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Firebase persists the user info in local storage and automatically restores it when the app/page reloads, this requires that it makes an asynchronous call to the server and thus may not be ready by the time your check runs.

Instead of depending on `currentUser`, you'll want to [listen for changes to the authentication state](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state) through the `authStateChanges` stream. Most apps wrap this in a `StreamBuilder` and then show the correct screen based on the stream state and last event.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that can be resolved by using `async` . the problem is you are getting response in future but the action is performed before. Please check the following documentation for detailed overview:
https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await